# How to I get a reference to WPF's splash screen?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, splash-screen

WPF allows you to create a splash screen by [adding an image file to your project and setting its build property to SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application). The great thing about this feature (as opposed to rolling my own splash screen) is that the splash screen is shown *immediately* while the WPF app starts up (which can take a lot of time on older machines).

Is it possible to get a reference to this splash screen at runtime? There is the [`SplashScreen` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen(v=vs.110).aspx), but, unfortunately, it does not have a static "Current" method or something like this.

Any kind of reference to the underlying splash screen window ([`Window` instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) or even just the underlying Windows API window handle) would be fine for me.

**Background:** There's a [bug in WPF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/afe25356-06dc-4d28-b5ad-6dfbdfe065a1/how-to-use-wpf-splashscreen-class-under-net-framework-45-windows-8?forum=wpf) which causes the app to crash if the application's main window is closed while the splash screen is still visible. The bug [won't be fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/784977/splashscreen-still-open-during-process-exit-can-result-in-crash-on-exit), so I need to work around it by keeping my app "alive" until the splash screen has faded away. I currently do this by `Thread.Sleep(2000)`-ing in my main window's `Closing` event, but that's ugly and unreliable. I'd rather wait (only) until the splash screen window is gone.

Comment: `Sleep` is totally fine, there is nothing on screen while you waiting anyway, nobody care if some process stays for a second longer. Or do you have some other issues? You can move `Sleep` into `App` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could show and close a `SplashScreen` explicitly yourself in the `OnStartup` method or constructor of your `App` class in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("splash.png");
    splashScreen.Show(false);

    //init your main window here...

    splashScreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Then you should be able to control the lifetime of both the splash screen and your application.

Comment: Will this show the splash screen as early as the Build Action method?

Comment: Yes, you could put it before the call to the base class' method or in the constructor of the App class. The App class gets created the first thing that happens in the Main method of the application so there is no earlier than this.