# Why TriggerEvent "Loaded" binded command doesn't work for App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to load a Splash Screen when my app loads.
The LoadSplashScreen is a Delegate Command that checks if there is already another program running, if not it shows the splash screen.

But to check the property, I need to trigger a Command when the App.xaml is loaded.

It shows me that "Triggers can't be attached to elements of type Application"
And other errors also which I think are related to the first one where it says that Triggers binding can only be derived types of "DependencyObject".

Here's the xaml code:

```
<Application x:Class="FST.CWI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:FST.CWI.Sources.ViewModel"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadSplashScreen}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Application.Resources>
        <viewModel:BaseViewModel x:Key="BaseVM" />
        <viewModel:AppViewModel x:Key="AppVM" />
        <viewModel:GeneralViewModel x:Key="GeneralVM" />
        <viewModel:SteeringViewModel x:Key="SteeringVM" />
        <viewModel:AdvancedViewModel x:Key="AdvancedVM" />
        <viewModel:SittingViewModel x:Key="SittingVM" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Well yes this is your problem. You'd need to use something that inherits from dependencyobject. For example MainWindow. Or you'd need a different approach eg new up and show a window in code.

Comment: Isn't there a workaround to make it work with Application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wpf has a spash screen feature, maybe you can use it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application

It can display an image until your MainWIndow appears.

Comment: This is what I'm using, but I'm trying to put some logic and not load it if there's another program that is running. The SplashScreen works fine, it's the binding to the command that shows the SplashScreen and contains logic that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118045/how-to-i-get-a-reference-to-wpfs-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

Application is not a dependency object so don't try and use anything which relies on it being one. Because that just isn't going to work.

Remove the startup url from app.xaml that opens mainwindow.
Instead point it to an override for onstartup in you app.xaml.cs

```
<Application …
           Startup="OnStartup">
```

And of course your code in app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    //  Your logic here


}
```

Put whatever your logic in there and new up, show whichever window or whatever you like.

Which will look something very roughly like:

```
SplashScreen ss = null;
if ( your criteria goes here)
{
    ss = new SplashScreen("whatever.bmp");
    ss.Show();
}
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

if ( your criteria goes here )
{
    ss.Close();
}

mw.Show();
```